# Including NULL results as Zero when using COUNT and SUM

Tags: sql, count, null

I'm completely new to SQL and I'm working on creating a data feed from point of sale software for third party analysis. Here are the requirements for the CSV that will be uploaded to the data feed:

> The .CSV file should contain rows with the following values:
>   The STORE ID indicates a unique store identifier (i.e. Store1), and should include your chain name (in the same format as it appears the file name) and the particular store number. This should not include any spaces or punctuation, before or after the comma.
>
> > -The DATE in MM/DD/YYYY format
> >
> > -HH corresponds to the appropriate hour using the 24 hour clock (0-23, with 0 indicating Midnight to 1 AM).
> >
> > -The COUNT value is the transaction count for that specific hour of operation, as defined in the previous section.
> >
> > -The SALES DOLLARS value corresponds to the total amount of sales accumulated within that hour, as defined in the previous section. Note that there cannot be commas used as thousands separators, or dollar sign symbols.
> >
> > -The TRAFFIC PLACEHOLDER is a required field, but should be left as a 0 value.
> >
> > > Sample Output
> > >
> > > Wxyz434,02/28/2011,13,56,446.34,0
> > >
> > > Wxyz434,02/28/2011,14,61,482.28,0
> > >
> > > Wxyz434,02/28/2011,15,63,382.80,0

I've been able to locate the tables within the Data Export Utility within my POS software, and I've used this SQL Query:

```
/***** Script for Headcount Data *****/
select [STR_ID]
  ,[BUS_DAT]
  ,[TKT_TIM_HR]
              ,COUNT ([TKT_NO])
  ,SUM ([SAL_TOT])

from MyData.dbo.VI_PS_TKT_HIST
where BUS_DAT between '04-24-2013 00:00:00' and '04-24-2013 11:59:59' and 
TKT_TIM_HR between '10' and '19'

group by BUS_DAT, STR_ID, TKT_TIM_HR
```

With partial results:

> > "STR_ID","BUS_DAT","TKT_TIM_HR","Field","Field_1"
> >
> > "1","4/24/2013 12:00:00.000 AM",19,1,270.27
> >
> > "11","4/24/2013 12:00:00.000 AM",10,1,32.95
> >
> > "11","4/24/2013 12:00:00.000 AM",12,4,229.24
> >
> > "11","4/24/2013 12:00:00.000 AM",13,1,137.28

You'll note that TKT_TIM_HR is the HOUR that the ticket is processed, and there were no tickets processed in the 11 hour.

How can I modify the query so that a row exists for the 11 hour, even though there are no tickets/sales numbers present? (Count NULL as Zero??)

Thank you very much for any assistance,,

Tyler

Comment: FYI what you're trying to achieve is called `filling gaps in sparse data` and is usually best done via `partitioned outer join` to a table (or query) that lists every day/hour combination in the range that you need. What RDBMS are you using? Is it `mysql`, `oracle`, `sqlite`,etc?

Comment: And note that if `partitioned outer join` isn't available, you can use a `left outer join` on your table of dates and hours.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. I have access to SQL Server Studio 2008 R2, however the script is being used to generate a data export from the POS software itself (Counterpoint SQL).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if it's available to you, is to set up the column to not allow nulls and to have a default value of 0.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Unfortunately I cannot modify the database itself, only query it. Also, there is not another table that includes TKT_TIM_HR, so would using a LEFT JOIN be problematic?

Comment: A left join would not be problematic.

Comment: Thanks again, Dan. I'm having trouble finding information on using a left join on a column that is already selected. If I remove it from the first query, do I then add the left join as a second SELECT TKT_TIM_HR FROM MYDATA.dbo.VI_PS_TKT_HIST? I apologize if there is an easily located answer elsewhere, I've been researching for three days and my brain is a bit fried.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a "calendar" relation to use as a sub-query that can be the LHS of a LEFT OUTER JOIN. If you only need to report by the hour, something like this will do:

```
select [Hour], AmPm
from (
  select Hour= 1 union all select  2 union all select  3 union all select  4 union all
  select Hour= 5 union all select  6 union all select  7 union all select  8 union all
  select Hour= 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12 
) H
cross join ( select AmPm = 'am' union all select 'pm'
) T
order by AmPm,[Hour]
```

Comment: Thank you Pieter, I will try this. If Hour is a two digit 24-hour format, I simply continue the union all select until all 24 are generated?

Comment: Or, in that case you might just want to (a) change the AmPm to a * 2;  and (b) change the 1 to 12 to become 0 to 11; to give yourself hours from 0 to 23 with a bit less verbosity. If you find yourself re-using this, build it as a table in your DB.  The best thank you, of course, is a vote or an acceptance.